# Difference between removeFirstOccurrence and remove

Tags: java, list, collections

Is there any difference between the `remove(Object o)` method `(of List interface)` and `removeFirstOccurrence(Object o)` method `(of LinkedList class)` in the collections api?
I could see that both does the same i.e remove first occurrence of the object in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any difference between remove(Object o) method (of List
>   interface) and removeFirstOccurrence(Object o) method (of LinkedList
>   class) in collections framework?

These are two distinct methods, coming from two distinct interfaces.
The first one (`remove(Object o)`) is defined in the `java.util.Collection` interface.
The other one (`removeFirstOccurrence(Object o)` is defined in the `java.util.Deque` interface.

The first one (`remove(Object o)`) has a contract rather general in the `Collection` interface :

> Removes a single instance of the specified element from this
>   collection, if it is present...

But the `List` interface that extends `Collection` has a more specific contract :

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list,
>   if it is present (optional operation)....

One the other hand, the `removeFirstOccurrence(Object o)` defined in the `Deque` interface specifies a similar contract :

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this deque...

---

It turns out that the `LinkedList` implements both directly `List` and `Deque`. 
And as `List.remove(Object o)` and `Deque.removeFirstOccurrence(Object o)` specify a similar contract, it is really not surprising that the behavior and the implementation of these two methods in the `LinkedList` class be the same.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is **no difference**.

If you look at source of [`removeFirstOccurrence()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#l813), you'll see:

```
public boolean removeFirstOccurrence(Object o) {
    return remove(o);
}
```

The reason `LinkedList` has both is given in the javadoc of each:

[**`remove(Object o)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)
Specified by: [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) in interface `Collection<E>`
Specified by: [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) in interface `Deque<E>`
Specified by: [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) in interface `List<E>`

[**`removeFirstOccurrence(Object o)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeFirstOccurrence-java.lang.Object-)
Specified by: [`removeFirstOccurrence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#removeFirstOccurrence-java.lang.Object-) in interface `Deque<E>`

Answer (score 0):

No I do not think any difference is there both remove the first occurrence of element and return.More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i

Java API ArrayList remove.

```
  public boolean remove(Object o) {
            if (o == null) {
                for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
                    if (elementData[index] == null) {
                        fastRemove(index);
                        return true;
                    }
            } else {
                for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
                    if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
                        fastRemove(index);
                        return true;
                    }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

LinkedList removeFirstOccurrence

```
if (o == null) {
            for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
                if (x.item == null) {
                    unlink(x);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
                if (o.equals(x.item)) {
                    unlink(x);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
```